# I need multiple instances of a Controller in a Spring/JavaFX app

Tags: java, spring, javafx, autowired

I am trying to integrate JavaFX with Spring for the autowiring capabilities of Spring.

However I need to have multiple instance of myController class which I have yet been able to configure.

Using `fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);`, everytime I load the fxml file, I get the same instance of the myController class.
Without that line, I get different instances but the autowired myService inside myController is null.

What can I do to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm.
How can I mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the controller to have prototype scope (the service can still have the default singleton scope, so each instance of the controller has a reference to the same instance of the service).